# image on bar chart not always show

Tags: javascript, html, json, chart.js

I want to make image float above bar chart but when I acheived it it's not always show,It display only when mouseover on the bar  and error 404 keeps appear on log

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="6"></canvas>
    <script>
        new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
    //   data: [25, 59, 80, 76],
    data: [25, 59, 80, 76],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      labels: {
        render: 'image',
        textMargin: 10,
        images: [
          {
            src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMtU.png',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
          },
          null, 
          {
            src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMtU.png',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
          },
          null
        ]
      }
    },
    // layout: {
    //   padding: {
    //     top: 30
    //   }
    // },
    // legend: {
    //   display: false
    // },
    // scales: {
    //   yAxes: [{
    //     ticks: {
    //       beginAtZero: true
    //     }
    //   }]
    // }
  }
});
```

how can I make image always show on bar without mouseover and make error disappeared

Comment: can you share some pics please, i have tried your code and it work fine, i can see images on A and C

Comment: @Anis I'm a new user on stack overflow so I can't share image, this code work fine but when I apply it on other project with many css js libraries in one file , image only appear when I do mouse over on chart and error keeps showing every time I did. Do you have other solution to make this task done?

Comment: I use chart js 3.9.1 in my project